# I have a problem with my twitter bot and Github and Heroku: I cannot build that in heroku

Tags: python, github, heroku

I made a tweeter bot with python and I uploaded in github. I connected github to Heroku. When I try to build that in heroku, I get this error:

```
Build main 7f802d5f
There was an issue deploying your app. View the build log for details.

-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

What should I do. procfile and runtime is in main branch.

Answer (score 0):

To build your application Heroku does not only need the `runtime.txt` or the `Procfile` but also a requirements-file which contains your dependencies.

The [buildpack looks for a](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/main/bin/detect)  `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile`, while there are [other buildpacks that support poetry](https://elements.heroku.com/search/buildpacks?q=poetry).